# How to get only necessary <div> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to parse some information about writers with `BeautifulSoup` from wikidata.

Page: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39829

**Problem**

I need to parse the field "child" from the page. In the result I want to get 3 names. But instead of 3 names, I got 3 names + 2 extra values.

**Code**

```
children_html = soup.find('div', id='P40').find_all('div', class_='wikibase-snakview-variation-valuesnak')
children_list = [child.text.strip() for child in children_html]
print(children_list)
```

The result is:

```
['Joe Hill', 'Owen King', 'Naomi King', 'https://books.google.de/books?id=aPBbAgAAQBAJ', '81']
```

**Question**

Is there any way to get only name in the result:

```
['Joe Hill', 'Owen King', 'Naomi King']
```

The code should also work for other writers pages. Who could have less or more children

Comment: did you already try the Wikidata client library for Python? it's probably way better than parsing the web page. https://github.com/dahlia/wikidata

Comment: Yes. I've already tried. But it's slow. I even have a question about it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72893053/how-to-make-python-wikidata-client-library-run-faster

Comment: Maybe you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: no, i do not know why it's that slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close to your goal - simply change the class to `wikibase-statementview-mainsnak` that is more specific:

```
soup.find('div', id='P40').find_all('div', class_='wikibase-statementview-mainsnak')
```

As alternative you could use `css selectors` for short hand:

```
soup.select('#P40 .wikibase-statementview-mainsnak')
```

Both will give you:

```
['Joe Hill', 'Owen King', 'Naomi King']
```

---

**Be aware** *To avoid running into `NoneType` errors, you should always check if elements exists*

```
if soup.find('div', id='P40'):
    children_html = soup.find('div', id='P40').find_all('div', class_='wikibase-statementview-mainsnak')
    children_list = [child.text.strip() for child in children_html]
    print(children_list)
else:
    children_list = []
    print('no child found')
```

or in one line that is genarating an empty list in case there ar no children:

```
children_list = [child.text.strip() for child in soup.select('#P40 .wikibase-statementview-mainsnak')]
```